# Change font in wetty.js

Tags: node.js, fonts

Im working with [wetty.js](https://github.com/krishnasrinivas/wetty) and i want to change the font.

I tried to adding a new font in the index.html, wetty.scss and so on.
Also i tried to change the font throught xterm.js (dependency package for wetty.js)
Tried to adding font in Xresources without luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disable the option Allow Web Sites To Choose Their Own in firefox

Steps:
Type about:preferences#content in the address bar. Across from fonts and colors, press the Advanced button. On the bottom, turn off Allow Web Sites To Choose Their Own.

source: https://support.mozilla.org/es/questions/1204639#answer-1076474